# Is there any way to debug sql-clr function of visual studio from ssms

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I have a CLR-Function written in C#, and the wrapper written is SQL. I want to debug that CLR-Function .dll from SQL Server Management Studio. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot debug a CLR function directly in SSMS. You need to use Visual Studio and have the source code for the dll.

Here's a link to a Microsoft site which shows you how to set up CLR debugging.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165053(v=vs.100).aspx